# When not to use autocorrelation structure in time series?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, acf-pacf

I have time series data of animal carcasses submitted to a testing laboratory on a monthly basis for three years to test for disease. This disease acts very quickly and kills the host within a couple of days, hence if there was autocorrelation in my data I was expecting AR(1) or AR(2), nothing more.

I have created ACF and pACF plots and find that there is significant autocorrelation in my data at AR(5), [image: see here].

I cannot explain this biologically, it makes no sense to me that the number of animal carcasses submitted one month could be correlated with the number submitted five months prior or five months later. I think this autocorrelation pattern may be due to a bi-modal annual pattern in my data relating to disease transmission which is influenced by the birth of a new susceptible cohort of animals, 
[image: see here].

I do not think the circulation of disease one month (the number of carcasses submitted one month) is influenced by or influences disease (carcasses submitted) five months prior/later.

So my question is: Should a correlation structure be included in a model in such a situation? Where there is some evidence of autocorrelation in the data at a particular AR(#), but you believe that it is explained by some sort of seasonal/annual pattern as opposed to something happening one month influencing what is happening another month?

My gut feeling is to not include any correlation structure in my model.

P.S I am new to using GAMMs and time series analysis so any advice, even unrelated to the question, is much appreciated.

Thanks